# karate api testing : Is response header validated based on request headers

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I have an api
example -

/get/userBundle

Request header - Accept = application/zip

Response assertion - status == 200.

If response status = 200, but response is NOT of type zip but json response or any other format, will the test fail without having any other assertion for response header or response body.

is it necessary to add assertion of response body to be zip or response header to be application/zip ? or response type is by default validated based on request header (Accept)

Answer (score 0):

Response headers are not validated automatically. You can easily add them: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-header

Here is an example:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* method get
* match header Content-Type == 'application/json'
```

Personally I don't think these add much value.

Comment: thanks Peter for responding. What I mean is , if request header 'Accept' = 'application/zip', will this enforce API response to be of type zip? Will API call fail if response is anything other than type zip, like json response or plain text.

Comment: @sumit no. that's what I said, if you want to assert that the response has some specific header you have to do it yourself